# Maximum path sum in 2D integer matrix with multiple conditions - Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

There is a robot on a rectangular isosceles triangle:

```
2
12 15
10 14 19
-9 -30 12 8
-8 -50 1 14 9
99 150 11 10 9 7
```

It is situated at the top-left corner. It can move one step at a time in two ways: bottom-right or down. The matrix can have negative and positive elements.

The simple question of finding the maximum path sum would be damn easy. For this problem the following recurrence relations hold:

```
cost[i][j] = mat[i][j] + max(cost[i-1][j-1], cost[i-1][j]);
```

The implementation is given below.

There are two additional conditions:

- The robot can stop whenever he wants, he doesn't have to arrive on the bottom line to have the biggest sum.
- You can opt for deleting a point (and only one) from the entire maximum path you obtained at the end, in order to maximize the sum.

How can I modify my solution to account for the above conditions?

Here's the code I wrote for the moment.

```
int maxPathSum(vector<vector<int>> mat, int n)
{
    vector<vector<int>> cost(n+2, vector<int>(n+2, 0));
    vector<vector<char>> pred(n+2, vector<char>(n+2, '$'));

    cost[1][1] = mat[1][1];
    pred[1][1] = 'S';
    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cost[i][1] = cost[i-1][1] + mat[i][1];
        pred[i][1] = 'U';
    }



    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
        for(int j=2; j<=n; j++) {
            if(i>=j) {
                cost[i][j] = mat[i][j] + max(cost[i-1][j-1],cost[i-1][j]);
                if(cost[i-1][j-1]>cost[i-1][j]) {
                    pred[i][j] = 'D';
                }
                else {
                    pred[i][j] = 'U';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int maxSum = 0;
    int posi, posj;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        if(mat[n][i] > maxSum) {
            maxSum = cost[n][i];
            posi = n;
            posj = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "The max sum is " << maxSum << endl;

    pairs p;
    vector<pairs> result;

    while(pred[posi][posj] != '$')
    {

        p.a = posi;
        p.b = posj;
        result.push_back(p);
        if (pred[posi][posj] == 'D') {
            posi -= 1;
            posj -= 1;
        }
        else {
            posi -= 1;
        }
    }

    reverse(result.begin(),result.end());
    cout<<"A maximum path is "<<endl;
    for(auto it:result) {
        cout<<it.a<<" "<<it.b<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be much more specific and make your own tries in terms of code. Otherwise it's hard to help, because no one knows your maturity level and where to start.

Comment: @user4581301 I have already done the problem without taking in mind that the robot can stop anywhere and the negative valued inputs, I was just asking for some advice on how to implement it with those conditions applied.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not asking for code, I'm just asking for a hint on how to do it...

Comment: @4386427: There are better ways to respond to people than that. Writing software by starting to write code before planning does not engender good design. Unfortunately, that means your comment is bad advice. Additionally, it comes across as unfriendly and unkind. You can guide people to asking better questions or to useful ways to think about programming tasks without being unkind.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight regardless, you should lead with what you have accomplished so far, even if it only provides a baseline such as what Stephan Lechner's looking for.

Comment: @user4581301 Ok, I'll edit the post to show you what I have done so far, didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: Also, add the rules for how the robot moves. I assume it must move one row down, and at most one column left or right, on each move. But that should be specified in the question.

Comment: I'm guessing the robot can either move down or right, or stop? I would consider a recursive search called once per node that returns the best route found when visiting that node. At each node, you need to decide whether you get a better score by moving down, or right, or stopping. The question is what the function returns

Comment: @user3386109 Edited the post.

Comment: @TimRandall How would you know if stopping will give you a better score? What if you have to choose between stopping(0 points) going down (-5) or going left (-7) and then at the next step you would have going down(+2500). The stopping procedure wasn't a great choice then.

Comment: I suggest you explicitly present the recurrence relations you used. They should be amended to account for any additional conditions. I don't understand condition (3). If a robot can stop at any point, condition (1), condition (3) seems superfluous: deleting the last point is equivalent to just stopping one step earlier. Or "at the end" does not mean the last point?

Comment: @Evg The recurrence is shown in the code. 

cost[i][j] = the maximum sum from the top till the (i,j) point.
cost[i][j] = mat[i][j] + maximumOf(cost[i-1][j-1] + cost[i-1][j]) the 2 possible ways to come from

Comment: The idea behind recursion is that it would consider every possible route. You can't evaluate the highest score gained by visiting a node until you've evaluated every possible route from that point onward. So the data needed to store "best route" would be the entire sequence of nodes visited. And its score would be the total of the node values, excluding the lowest.

Comment: @Evg Sorry, that was a misunderstanding, at the end you will get a path with the maximum sum, you can erase only one point from that path, doesn't matter which one, so that you can maximize the sum.

Comment: Why is it too broad? Seems to be a pretty concrete question.

Comment: @Evg first cut of the question was too open-ended and all but the most recent close vote was set in place before the question was edited. Likely none of the initial 4 close voters came back to retract the vote before the fifth vote locked the question. At 2000 rep you may have the ability to join me in voting to re-open. If re-opened it may be re-closed afterward, but it'll at least get closed for a better reason.

Comment: Condition (1) is easy: just find max in the whole table `cost`, not its bottom line. Condition (3), idea of solution: instead of `(current position)` as a state use `(current position, hopped flag)`, where `hopped flag` is true if a robot hopped over one cell along its path. Then you can easily write new recurrence relations.

Comment: Bah. 3000 rep needed to cast reopen votes.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for your kindness, I appreciate it!

Comment: @user4581301, I hope comments will be enough for OP to solve the problem. The question is a good one.

Comment: @Evg What a brilliant idea, I might need some further explanations regarding the hopped flag.

Comment: @Evg I was thinking that I could see which is the lowest element that has been added to the sum in the path and then mark it as deleted, or hopped and add the value to the sum itself *(-1).

Comment: @Evg Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Evg I don't know what UVa is unfortunately. I understood that part, but when do I know it's the proper time to hop over a specific cell? That's what I don't get.

Comment: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php

Comment: Working from the top, the best scores are {2}, {14,17}, {24,31,36}. The fourth row is where things get tricky. The best scores for the fourth row are {15N/24S, 1N/31S, 48N, 44N}. Let me explain the notation. `N` means the number can be achieved without a skip. `S` means the number used a skip. So `15N/24S` means the best score is either 15 with No skip, or 24 with a skip. Which is to say that the DP table needs two entries for each position: the first entry is the best score without a skip, and the second entry is the best score using a skip.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for the hint, mate!

Comment: To summarize. State space should be `(i, j, false/true)`. The recurrence relations are `cost(i, j, false) = max{mat(i, j) + cost(i-1, j-1, false), mat(i, j) + cost(i-1, j, false)}`, `cost(i, j, true) = max{cost(i-1, j-1, false), cost(i-1, j, false), mat(i, j) + cost(i-1, j-1, true), mat(i, j) + cost(i-1, j, true)}`.